# Find all meromorphic functions $f: C \to C$ s.t. $|f(z)|=1$ wherever $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

> **Problem.** Find all meromorphic functions $f: C \to C$ s.t. $|f(z)|=1$ wherever $|z|=1$.

$f(z)$ should be like $f=g(z)/h(z)$, where $g(z)$, $h(z)$ are holomorphic functions. I know that if $f(z)$ is also meromorphic at infinity, then it is easy to conclude that $f(z) = g(z)/h(z)$, where $g(z)$, $h(z)$ are polynomials. But now this condition is not satisfied, so I was stuck.

Thanks for opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ has a finite number of zeros and poles on $C$; moreover, there is an open set $O$ containing $C$ in which there are no other poles or zeros. Let $Z$ be the set zeros and $P$ the set of poles of $f$ in $C$ (both counted with multiplicity.) Let 
$$
g(z)=\Bigl(\prod_{p\in P}\frac{z-p}{1-\bar p\,z}\Bigl)\Bigl(\prod_{\zeta\in Z}\frac{z-\zeta}{1-\bar \zeta\,z}\Bigr)^{-1}f(z).
$$
Then $g$ is holomorphic in $=$ (after removing the removable singularities at the poles and zeros of $f$), has no zeros in $O$ and $|g(z)|=1$ if $|z|=1$. It follows that $g$ is constant, and
$$
f(z)=a\,\Bigl(\prod_{p\in P}\frac{z-p}{1-\bar p\,z}\Bigl)^{-1}\Bigl(\prod_{\zeta\in Z}\frac{z-\zeta}{1-\bar \zeta\,z}\Bigr)
$$
where $a$ is a constant with $|a|=1$.

Comment: Wow, the construction of g is really fantastic! It successfully removes all the poles and zeros of f, as well as keeping the norm at the boundary of the circle! That work out smoothly!