# Find all meromorphic functions $f$ s.t. $|f(z)|=1$ wherever $|z|=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

> **Problem.** Find all meromorphic functions $f$ s.t. $|f(z)|=1$ wherever $|z|=1$.

I know this problem has been solved in [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208577/find-all-meromorphic-functions-s-t-f-1-when-z-1). However, I cannot show $f$ has only finite number of poles and zeros. Any hints?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3883269/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/783741/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thanks!But I think these examples are just about functions in the disc.I want to know why meromorphic functions in the complex plane satisfying the condition above has finite poles and zeros.

Comment: A meromorphic function in the plane is in particular meromorphic in the disk, therefore those solutions can all be applied to your case.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, if two meromorphic functions are equal on the disk, they are also equal on $\mathbb C$. So if some set of meromorphic functions are the only ones that satisfy this condition on the disk, they are also the only ones satisfying it on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much!

Comment: @eyeballfrog Oh,I see.Thank you!